# Regex : split string based on first occurrence, with occurance

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am terrible at regex. Please have pity and give me a hand.
I am trying to split a string by the first occurrence of `And` (case sensitive), into an array with a length of 2. I have no idea were to begin, so can someone help me?

```
 var strArr = "Thing And other thing".split(/magic regex/);
 expect(strArr).to.deep.equal(["Thing","And other thing"]);

 var strArr = "Thing and other thing".split(/magic regex/);
 expect(strArr).to.deep.equal(["Thing and other thing", ""]);

 var strArr = "One Thing And other thing And yet another thing".split(/magic regex/);
 expect(strArr).to.deep.equal(["One Thing","And other thing And yet another thing"]);

 var strArr = "yep, just one thing".split(/magic regex/);
 expect(strArr).to.deep.equal(["yep, just one thing", ""]);
```

---

**UPDATE** this is working exactly the way I need it to, but its still ugly:

```
  parser = function(str) {
    var spl;
    spl = str.split(/\s(?=And )/);
    if (spl.length > 1) {
      spl = [spl.shift(), spl.join(" ")];
    } else {
      spl = [str, ''];
    }
    return spl;
  };
```

Comment: Did you try just `string.split('And')` ?

Comment: To just check for the existance of a string within a string, you could use indexOf

Comment: Yes. It does not fulfill all the unit tests.

Comment: @adeneo I could write a function and if statement and do it all with indexof. But I thing regex would be more elegant.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: `expect(str.indexOf('And') > -1).to.be.true`. Not much different.

Comment: @FelixKling sure, can you provide an example of doing it on one line?

Comment: Uh what? Isn't that one line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a cleaner implementation of working code. As such it would be more appropriate on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName the working code is based on answers below. Its did not exist in the original post.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Yes, I'm aware. The original post is off topic because it doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding, so it's a choose your own close vote adventure. I picked the reason that best matches the current question state.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName fair enough. I have voted to close as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for a regular expression for that. Just get the first index of `"And"` in the string:

```
var i = str.indexOf("And");
var strArr;
if (i == -1) {
  strArr = [ str ];
} else {
  strArr = [ str.substr(0, i), str.substr(i) ];
}
```

Comment: Though this will also find `BAnd`

Comment: Is there no way to do this more elegantly with regex?

Comment: @anubhava: You can look for `" And "` if you like, but the question didn't specifying that it should only look for an "And" that is a separate word.

Comment: So far this is working the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

While Guffa's method works, if you end up needing to do this the regex way, the following will work (via a positive lookahead):

```
var str = "Thing And other thing";
var spl = str.split(/\s(?=And\s)/);
if (spl.length > 1)
    spl = [spl.shift(), spl.join(" ")];
```

To test:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(spl));
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/8qEnz/)

**Updated** to ensure it splits on `[space]And[space]`

Comment: But that splits on every occurrence, not only on the first one.

Comment: @FelixKling Right, fixed it.

Comment: If there is no `'And'` this returns an array of 2 with `[0]` being `''`

Comment: @Fresheyeball Fixed that too ;) thanks

Comment: Ok, found one more issue. `"Andthing"` gets recognized, it needs to be matching for `" And "`

Comment: @Fresheyeball OK, though that's still legitimately the first occurrence of And ;) Guess you could use `\s(?=And\s)`, but that wouldn't match `This And.` (not that you'd want to, but...)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing a simple [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then checking if the array has one or two

`strArr.split("And", 2).length`;

Comment: I don't think this would result in the desired output. About the `limit` parameter: *"The split method still splits on every match of `separator`, but it truncates the returned array to at most `limit` elements."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split